# How to design nice structure of an module so the import would not be horrendeous?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I currently have a situation with my framework where if I want to import an API, my import looks hideous.

Structure looks like this:

```
|- main.py
|- Scripts
|  |- dir_1
|     |- script_1.py
|  |- dir_2
|     |- script_2.py
|- Utilities
   |- api_dir
      |- base_dir
      |  |- base_class.py
      |- specific_dir
      |  |- specific_class.py
      |- api.py
```

FWK is currently written in a way that when a script that is in `Scripts` directory needs to use one of the `Utilities`, import has to look like this:

```
import Utilities.api_dir.api
```

What I would like to do is something like this:

```
import api
```

I'm aware that i can append each `api_dir` into `sys.path` but I would like to know if there is more cleaner way of doing something like this?

Also I would like to know about naming conventions in case like this. How should I call my `api.py` and how the directory `api_dir` should be called?

If I would name my `api.py` like `some_specific_functionality.py` and `api_dir` `some_specific_functionality` currently import would look something like this:

```
import Utilities.some_specific_functionality.some_specific_functionality
```

And I would like to avoid this.

Comment: You know you can do `from Utilities.api_dir import api`, right?

Comment: Yes I do know, but I was never keen on using that `from` form.

Comment: @SirDrinksCoffeeALot Any particular reason why not to use the form `from ... import ...` ? It is used a lot in the Python environment and libs.

Comment: Not really, it is just my personal preference. `import ...` looks cleaner to me.

Comment: I forgot to mention that scripts that are located in `Scripts` directory are not meant to be standalone, they can only be ran through the framework itself. I'm saying this because it would be totally valid to have something like `import api`.